# EC2 Detailed Monitoring vs CloudWatch Agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What's the whole purpose of EC2 Detailed Monitoring? Is it just about sending metrics with more frequency to CloudWatch?

I was wondering if it's capable of monitoring Memory and Swap like the CloudWatch Agent is, or if its purpose is simply to "send data faster" to CloudWatch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it just about sending metrics with more frequency to CloudWatch

Almost. You get faster metrics, and also ability to aggregate them across similar instances.

> I was wondering if it's capable of monitoring Memory and Swap like the CloudWatch Agent is,

No. You need Agent for that.